# Flutter Stepper with ListView not rendering

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using a Stepper and one of the steps has a ListView.builder inside of it, like so:

```
steps: <Step>[
          new Step(
            title: new Text('Select Ingredients'),
            content: _buildPantryStep(),
            isActive: _currentStep >= 0,
            state: _currentStep >= 0 ? StepState.complete : StepState.disabled,
          )

_buildPantryStep() {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      FutureBuilder(
        future: _pantryMemoizer.future,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Expanded(
                child: PantryIngredients(ingredientList: ingredientList));
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return new Text('An error occurred retrieving your pantry');
          } else {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      )
    ]);
  }
```

where PantryIngredients is mostly this:

```
Widget getList() {
    if (widget.ingredientList.isEmpty) {
      return Text("There are no items in your pantry. Let's add some!");
    } else {
      return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: widget.ingredientList.length,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            if ((filter == null || filter.trim() == "") ||
                widget.ingredientList[index].ingredient.name
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .contains(filter.toLowerCase())) {
              return IngredientListEntry(widget.ingredientList[index]);
            } else {
              return Container(height: 0, width: 0);
            }
          });
    }
  }
```

I can see where it does make it into the getList() function and the ingredientList is populated with items. However, the debugger never makes it into the actual itemBuilder function, and the Step content starts out as the CircularProgressIndicator but then after the Future completes, the content is just blank.

If I change the

```
return Expanded(child: PantryIngredients(ingredientList: ingredientList))
```

to be something like

```
return Container(height: 500, width: 500, child: PantryIngredients(ingredientList: ingredientList))
```

then it does render. So, it seems to be something with the Expanded inside of the Step that isn't jiving, or I'm just doing something really stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be with sizing and layout. Here are a couple of comments I can do without actually trying things:

1. `Expanded` usually goes directly in `Column`. You have a `FutureBuilder` in between. Try to move the `Column` inside the `FutureBuilder` so that `Expanded`'s parent is `Column`.
2. As far as I know, `Step`s need to give their own sizes. What you are trying to do with `Column`/`Expanded` is to say "please take up all available size". However, `Step` is probably expecting that size from its child. You should decide on a size for your column and wrap it with a `SizedBox`.